# Geocoder's autocomplete only shows 26px in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, css

I've got a map on [GitHub](https://github.com/hoge6b01/mapcontroler/blob/master/index.html) (I have removed everything that isn't needed). The problem is that the geocoding widget doesn't show the search results completely:

[image: geocoding_autocomlete]

I guess this happens due to a custom zoom bar control that includes a Zoom Home function which controls the width to 26px. Removing the`.leaflet-bar a` part leads to smaller icons but to fully result display.

Does anyone have a hint on how to have big icons and full size result display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set a style specific to those dropdown elements

```
.leaflet-control-mapbox-geocoder-results a {width: 100%}
.leaflet-control-mapbox-geocoder-results a:hover {width: 100%;}
```

you may also want to make the input a bit wider, something like

```
.leaflet-control-mapbox-geocoder-results {width: 250px;}
.leaflet-control-mapbox-geocoder.active .leaflet-control-mapbox-geocoder-wrap {width: 250px;}
```

its seems strange that the input does not update with the selected item from the dropdown, [but that seems to be how this geocoding control works](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geocoding-auto/)

Comment: Adding the first two lines did the job. Could get the second to work due to my limited coding knowledge (if you would like to add as a working example feel free...) Thank you so much. One question: what option would likely be the better choice to adapt mobile devices? and a second: is it possible to change font size? seems quite big for now. thanks